# Support of a function and the struggle...

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

The concept of support is very confusing to me, I'm just getting used to it.

Lets consider $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb R^n$ an open set, $C^1_c(\Omega):=\{f\in C^1(\Omega)\mid\operatorname{supp}(f)\text{ is compact and $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset\Omega$}\}$.

> Let $f\in C^1_c(\Omega)$, prove that: $\mathtt {(1)}$ $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\in C^0_c(\Omega)$ and that: $$\begin{array}{cc} \mathtt {(2)} &\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0, & \forall \;i=1,\dots,n. \end{array}$$

$\mathtt {(1)}$ Because $f\in C^1(\Omega)$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\in C^0(\Omega)$. Now we have to prove that $\operatorname{supp}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})$ is compact and $\operatorname{supp}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})\subset\Omega$. After a few tries, I thought showing that $\operatorname{supp}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})\subseteq\operatorname{supp}(f)$ was the way to prove this.

Lets assume there's a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\in \operatorname{supp}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})$ such that $(x_n)\to x_o$, where $x_o\not\in\operatorname{supp}(f)$, then $f(x_o)=0$. On the other hand, we also have that $x_o\in \operatorname{supp}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})$, then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_o)\not=0$, but also $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_o)=0$, since $f(x_o)=0$, wich is a contradiction. Then it follows that $\operatorname{supp}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})\subseteq\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset \Omega$, hence $\operatorname{supp}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})$ is compact and $\operatorname{supp}(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i})\subset \Omega$. 

(*Is this correct?*)

$\mathtt {(2)}$ Here I think we have to make induction on $n$. So let's see the base $n=1$, i.e., $\Omega \subseteq\Bbb R$ open. Let's define 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) & x\in\Omega \\ 0 & x\in \Bbb R\setminus\Omega \end{cases}$$
Where this function satisfies $F\in C^1_c(\Bbb R)$, if $f\in C^1_c(\Omega)$. In this case follows that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\equiv\frac{df}{dx}=f'$. Also 
$$F'(x)=\begin{cases} f'(x) & x\in\Omega \\ 0 & x\in \Bbb R\setminus\Omega \end{cases}$$
We defined $F$ because we know that $$\int _{\Omega}f:=\int_{\Bbb R^n} F$$
Then $$\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\int_{\Omega} f'=\int_{\Bbb R^n} F'$$
I keep thinking *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*, but it really doesn't help, and I don't see how this equals to zero!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a) if $f$ is 0 outside $C$, does it not follow that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ is also 0 outside of $C$, i.e. $\text{supp}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \subset \text{supp} \ f \subset \Omega$, $\forall i$? Since $\text{supp} \ f$ is compact and $\text{supp} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ is closed, this gives you $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \in C^0_C(\Omega)$.

For b) think about how $\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ and $\int_{\partial \Omega} f$ are related and how $f$ behaves on $\partial \Omega$ (since $\Omega$ is open, $\partial \Omega \cap \Omega = \emptyset$).

Comment: a) so... no struggle?
b) I've been thinking about it, I got that $\int_{\partial \Omega}f=0$, but I don't see any relation with $\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$...

Comment: a) recall that supp $f$ is the closure of $\{x| \ f(x) \neq 0 \}$. so, for any point outside supp $f$, there is a neighborhood where $f$ is identically 0. By definition of the derivative, this makes $\partial f / \partial x_i = 0$ in that neighborhood as well. 

for b) you might want to think about the case $n = 1$ first. since $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open, it can be written as a disjoint union of open intervals. Since supp $df/dx$ is compact it is contained in finitely many of those intervals. For an interval $(a,b)$, use FTC and the fact that $\int_{\partial (a, b)} f = f(b) - f(a)$

Comment: I have an idea for b); because of the change variable theorem we have $\int _{\Omega }g(f(x))(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}})=\int _{\mathbb{R}^n }g(y)dy$ so we choose $g=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0\ if\ i\neq j & \\ 1\ if i= j
 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$ so $g=(0,\dots,1,\dots,0)$ so $g(f)=g$

Comment: so $g(f(x))(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}})=(0,\dots,1,\dots,0)(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}},\dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}$ so $\int _{\Omega }\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}=\int _{\mathbb{R}^n}g$ but the integral of $g$ is cero, is this correct?

Comment: @lessthanepsilon **b**) what if we "enclose" $\Omega$ with a closed set? like a closed cube $Q=[a_1,b_1]\times\dots\times[a_n,b_n]$ and then do this: $\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\int_Q \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\int^b_a \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=f|^b_a=f(b)-f(a)=0-0=0$, even if $a$ or $b$ are in the $\partial[supp(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})]$ we still get zero... is that what you said?

Comment: For b) recall that supp $f$ is the closure of $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus f^{-1}(0)$, which is open and also the interior of supp $f$. Since $\partial \text{supp} \ f$ is supp $f$ minus this set, $f$ vanishes on the boundary. For $n =1$, use heine-borel to find an $N$ such that supp $f \subset [-N, N]$ and take the integral over this interval. For $n > 1$, what this should extend to slices as you had in mind above.